# Is there a way to insert a view in a node form?

Tags: views, nodes, forms

I have created a content-type based form (contact form) for anonymous users.
One of the fields in the form must displays a view.
This view is a slideshow view that displays different persons (site employees).

I want them to select an employee to where their comments will be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

Found it i can use Markup module to use php code in the field and use this code;

WHATEVER is the name of your view.

Comment: I mean MARKUP module*

Answer (score 0):

With [module_invoke()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke/7), you can display a view block wherever you like.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
<?php
views_embed_view($name, $display_id = 'default') 
?>
```

to embed a view. Here is the [doc](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) for that.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of modules that might do it (quotes included are from their project pages):

- [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva):

  > ... provides a Views display plugin that allows the output of a View to be attached to the content of any Drupal entity. The body of a node or comment, the profile of a user account, or the listing page for a Taxonomy term are all examples of entity content.
- [View reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewreference):

  > ... defines a field type View reference which creates a relationship to a Views display and allows the view to be displayed as the content of the field.
  >
  > This module is modelled on Node reference and usage is similar.
  >
  > Additionally, you may enter arguments for each view by a delimiter seperated list with support for PHP generated arguments.
- [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield):

  > ... provides a field that holds a reference to a View and renders it whenever the entity containing the field is displayed.